# Grails Spring Security Custom UserDetailsService (goal of Email in place of Username)

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using `Grails Spring Security Plugin 1.2.7.3` and would like to have the User authenticate via Email Address and Password.  I would like Email Address to be the primary Login ID.

I came across the following [Nabble post regarding case insensitive usernames](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Spring-Security-Plugin-Case-insensitive-usernames-td3811436.html), where the original poster is attempting to do the same.  However, I was a bit confused on a few points:

1. I understand that I need to write my own implementation of `UserDetailsService` and register it in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`.

   However, I wasn't sure which folder the custom implementation of `UserDetailsService` should go (best practices).  My guesses are either `/grails-app/services`, `/grails-app/utils`, or `/src/groovy`.  Has anyone done this before and where is the best place for the custom `UserDetailsService`?

   I read this chapter in the Docs: http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/11%20Custom%20UserDetailsService.html but I didn't really see guidance on what Grails folder to put it in.
2. I created my User domain class via s2 command:

   ```
   s2-quickstart com.philiptenn.security User Role Requestmap
   ```

   If I were to rename the field `User.username` to `User.email` so that my code is clearer, will I be in for a world of hurt?

   I did a Find Usages on this field, and one stuck out in **DefaultSecurityConfig.groovy**: `userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'username'`

   Could I just update this to read:
   **DefaultSecurityConfig.groovy**: `userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'email'`

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you pointed out, you can override the default security configs in your own `Config.groovy`, the options all start with `grails.plugins.springsecurity`, so it would be `grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'email'` ([docs](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#1.1%20Configuration%20Settings%20Now%20in%20Config.groovy)). That's the first thing I'd try. If you check out the source of the [GormUserDetailsService](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/GormUserDetailsService.groovy#L60), the default userDetailsService, you'll see it uses that property for the lookup.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I am now using email.  Just one more question ... where should I put a custom Spring Security `UserDetailsService`?  I am thinking `/grails-app/services`, is that the right place?

Comment: I was hoping someone else might weigh in on that, I noticed in several of my apps I have my `CustomUserDetailsService` in `/src/groovy` but can think of no good reason why it's there and not in `grails-app/services`.

Comment: No problem, thanks.  I'll probably put it in `src/groovy` since it sounds like that will work.

Comment: @doelleri - Classes in `/src/groovy` are just treated as "plain" spring beans, while Grails Services have much more done to them and are dealt with somewhat specially in terms of how they are wired in to things via Spring.

Comment: @cdeszaq - Since the custom UserDetailsService bean has to be declared in `resources.groovy`, does that make the equivalent?

Comment: Yes, and that's how you should do it (sorry if this comes 2 years after :-)). See http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/single.html#userDetailsService